# How can I enforce different DNS servers when connected to a VPN?

Tags: network-manager, dns, vpn

I have a variety of OpenVPN VPN servers I connect to from my Ubuntu 17.04 machine, all of which push DNS servers using the `dhcp-option DNS A.B.C.D` (which I know is a Windows extension, but that's how they're pushed). The DNS servers (for each provider) change rarely, so I can also enter them manually if need be.

I add a VPN using its `.ovpn` config file via Gnome's Network Settings ("+" > "Import from file..."), making it available only to the current user. By contrast, the physical connection is a wifi connection available to all users.

The VPN's DNS servers are simply not used by the system. If I just accept the config as given in the file, the VPN connects but the DNS servers don't even appear in the output of `systemd-resolve --status`. If I add them to the IPv4 settings manually, they do but are not used.

For example, before connecting, the output of `systemd-resolve --status` shows this at the end:

```
Link 3 (wlp3s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

`192.168.1.1` is my router. After connecting to the VPN I see this extra entry *above* the others:

```
Link 9 (tun0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: A.B.C.D
                      E.F.G.G
```

`A.B.C.D` etc. stand for the DNS of the VPN provider. However, I've confirmed via packet inspection that even with these new entries, DNS lookups are done via `192.168.1.1` which just uses my ISP's servers.

For completeness, `ip route show` gives:

```
$ ip route show
default via 10.7.7.1 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600 
10.7.7.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.7.182 metric 50 
I.J.K.L via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.193 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0 proto static scope link metric 600
```

(`I.J.K.L` is the VPN address.) It seems weird that there are too different default routes, but I guess the metric is meant to take care of that?

Whatever the cause, I want to be using the VPN provider's DNS when I'm connected to the VPN, and not use them when I'm not. I considered trying to create a second Network Manager profile for my wifi access point with the provider's DNS entries, but it turns out you can't create a second (or user specific) profile for an access point that Network Manager already knows about.

Things I'd prefer to avoid:

- Modify the `.ovpn` config files. I have about a hundred of these, and they're updated regularly by the VPN providers.
- Permanently change DNS servers for the system-wide connection used for wifi, or for the router itself. I only want to use the VPN's DNS servers when I'm connected to a VPN.
- Run a command manually every time I connect to a VPN. I or another user could easily forget to do this.