# Can I create two different profiles for one wifi network?

Tags: network-manager, dns

One of my attempts to work around [this problem with VPN DNS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936655/how-can-i-enforce-different-dns-servers-when-connected-to-a-vpn) in 17.04 was to duplicate my existing wifi connection but with different DNS entries.

But Gnome's Network Settings UI appears to have no way to add a connection to a wifi access point if the SSID is already known to another connection profile. If I try to add it as a hidden network (where I can manually enter the SSID), it simply detects that I already have a system wide profile for it and prompts me to authenticate to change it, preventing me from adding a second one.

Is it possible to have two different sets of connection settings to the one wifi access point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to directly manipulate the Network Manager config files.

Start by copying the file for the profile you want to duplicate:

```
$ cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
$ ls
My Wifi Connection  My VPN  Some Other Connection
$ sudo cp "My Wifi Connection" "My Wifi Connection 2"
```

You need to change a few things in the new config file for it to work properly. Firstly, the name. If you look inside the config file (you need `sudo` for this), you'll see it starts with something like:

```
[connection]
id=My Wifi Connection
uuid=a66c4104-742c-11e7-a31d-973b9fb99e77
type=wifi
```

Edit the file (with `sudoedit`) to change the name to something different eg. "My Wifi Connection 2" or whatever makes it special eg. "My Wifi Connection (special DNS)".

Secondly, it needs a distinct UUID. The problem is, since you just copied this, the "unique" identifier is shared by two connections. Generate a new UUID like so:

```
$ sudo apt install uuid
$ uuid
bd52b27c-742c-11e7-82d3-c3bd07dba910
```

...and replace the UUID in the new config file with this.

Restart Network Manager so it sees the new config:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Now for using it — you'll need to change connections via the command line, because Gnome doesn't this situation.

To turn off your existing connection, do:

```
$ sudo nmcli connection down "My Wifi Connection"
```

To turn on the new connection, do:

```
$ sudo nmcli connection up "My Wifi Connection 2"
```

If you named the connection *inside* the config file something different from the filename, use the name inside the config file.