# Can I have two "known wifi networks" with the same name?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

Problem: There are two wifi networks I want to connect to regularly.  But they have the same ssid.  As far as I can tell, I have to reconfigure my wifi settings (passwords and authentication methods not the same) each time I move between them.  I do not control either network, so cannot change their name.  Is there any way to have ubuntu remember two different wifi connections with the same ssid? (for instance, it could prompt me which settings to use when that given ssid is detected) How do I set this up?  I see the "known wifi networks" listing in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.  These comprise individual files named `WIFISSID.nmconnection`.  The contents of each file also lists the wifi ssid it is about.  What happens if the filename and the wifi ssid listed in the file disagree?  Can I just add two files `WIFISSID.nmconnection` and `WIFISSID2.nmconnection` which inside refer to the same ssid?

Comment: 2 same names is asking for problems.

Comment: Yes, create two wifi configurations, and use the BSSID field to differentiate between the two networks with the same name.

Comment: Duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/936817/can-i-create-two-different-profiles-for-one-wifi-network