# WiFi SSIDs with 2 almost identical names - OS glitch or security consern

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, security, hacking

I noticed that in the last few days my computer connects to the network automatically (i unset the autoconnect).

Today i opened the wifi network settings and noticed that i am connected to "myWifi 1". While my other "myWifi" existed. i disconnected from it, and connected to "myWifi", and the previous "myWifi 1" just vanished on the spot. I checked "myWifi" settings and it had the automatically connect settings unset as expected.

I was just wondering if there's something i dont know within ubuntu, or if i should change all my passwords.

i scanned the area with LinSSID and didn't find it. I did notice, and im not sure, that i might have another interface, one is my regular WLP0S20F3 and another named p2p-wlp0s20-7, idk if it has to do with anything, but i don't remember having this.

i cam across this [Can I create two different profiles for one wifi network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/936817/can-i-create-two-different-profiles-for-one-wifi-network)
can what happened to me be a result of trying to share my screen with a samsung tv using gnome network display (https://flathub.org/apps/org.gnome.NetworkDisplays)?

Comment: Is "myWifi" the name (SSID) of the network, or of the network interface on your computer? Enter the command `iwgetid`. The network interface is listed first, the network name last.

Comment: yes, the ssid, last (network name). sorry if i wasnt clear @Jos